# custom console keymap - cannot open include file us

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, console

I want to make a custom console keymap as described [in the Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration)

This is my file:

```
# /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/personal.map

include "us"

# swap Caps_Lock and Escape
keycode   1 = Caps_Lock
keycode  58 = Escape

# swap left Alt and Control
keycode  29 = Alt
keycode  56 = Control

# German stuff
keymaps 0-3
keycode 22 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode 24 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode 30 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode 31 = s S ssharp
```

When I try to load it with `loadkeys /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/personal.map`, I get:

```
cannot open include file us
syntax error, unexpected ERROR
```

`us` is in the result of `localectl list-keymaps`, of course.

If I replace `include "us"` with `include "linux-with-two-alt-keys"` as in the Arch Wiki example, it does work as expected.

Why can I not include the `us` map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick `strace loadkeys /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/personal.map`
shows that only `include` directories and current working directory
are searched for files to include and as one can check with `locate`:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate -r "keymaps.*\.inc$"
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/azerty-layout.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/compose.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/euro1.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-keys-bare.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-keys-extd.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-with-alt-and-altgr.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-with-modeshift-altgr.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-with-two-alt-keys.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/qwerty-layout.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/qwertz-layout.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/apple-a1048-base.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/apple-a1243-fn-reverse.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/apple-a1243-fn.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/mac-azerty-layout.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/mac-linux-keys-bare.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/mac-qwerty-layout.inc
/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/include/mac-qwertz-layout.inc
```

indeed all .inc files reside in a directories named `include`.

I wasn't able to find an explanation of include mechanism in kbd
manpages but it can also be deduced from reading the [source
code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd.git/tree/src/libkeymap/analyze.l#n101):

```
static const char *const include_dirpath0[] = {
    "",
    NULL
};
static const char *const include_dirpath1[] = {
    "",
    "../include/",
    "../../include/",
    NULL
};
static const char *const include_dirpath3[] = {
    DATADIR "/" KEYMAPDIR "/include/",
    DATADIR "/" KEYMAPDIR "/i386/include/",
    DATADIR "/" KEYMAPDIR "/mac/include/",
    NULL
};
```

You can also see that `.inc` suffix [are added to the included files
automatically](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd.git/tree/src/libkeymap/analyze.l#n118):

```
static const char *const include_suffixes[] = {
    "",
    ".inc",
    NULL
};
```

So, to make `loadkeys  /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/personal.map` you need:

```
zcat /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/us.map.gz > /usr/local/share/kbd/keymaps/us.inc
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this helped a lot! :)

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: yes, it works :)